# Do we really need "uipickerviewdelegate" tag along with "uipickerview"?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I've checked that [uipickerviewdelegate](/questions/tagged/uipickerviewdelegate) is a new tag and rejected the suggested edit adding it. But it said "the edit is already accepted" and now I see 3 questions with that tag.

Shall I enforce my rejection by rolling back the suggested edits that somehow got though or just leave it to the community to decide?

We already have [uipickerview](/questions/tagged/uipickerview).

Comment: I've got no idea about uipickerview but I've nipped a new tag in the bud before and it didn't return.

Comment: `UIPickerView != UIPickerViewDelegate` (of course you often don't need both tags, they still aren't the same thing).